# How to fix these syntax errors?

Tags: java, syntax-error

I am an amateur/beginner Java programmer. I wrote the following GUI class to practice the skills I teach myself.

I get so many syntax errors.

This is my class:

```
package MyGUIStuff;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel ("Register:");
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField (20);
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("File Writer");
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        pnl.add(lbl);
        pnl.add(jtf);

    jtf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String str = new String (jtf.getText());

                    File file = new File ("register.txt");
                    if (!file.exists())
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(str);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.close();

                    System.out.println("Done!");

                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
        });

        frame.add(pnl);

   }
}
```

How to fix the errors?

Comment: What errors?  You need to post the errors you are getting.

Comment: Where are the errors? What are the error messages? What didn't you understand about them?

Comment: please provide occurred error here,it w'll be helped to some to help to you

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix a huge list of errors is to ignore all the errors except the first one. Fix that, recompile, and fix the first error. Fix that, recompile, and fix the first error. And so on.

### First error

So the first error I get is:

```
MyFrame.java:50: error: illegal start of type
        });
         ^
```

I look at what's going on around line 50. I notice that the `actionPerformed` method is missing its closing brace. I insert it so that the code around line 50 looks like this:

```
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
```

Then I recompile and look at the list of errors.

### The only error left

One of the benefits of fixing only the first error and then recompiling is that several errors usually magically disappear. By fixing just the first error, we went from 6 errors down to only 1 error:

```
MyFrame.java:46: error: variable e is already defined in method actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
                }catch (IOException e){
                                    ^
```

I look around to see where `e` is declared. It's declared in two places: the argument to the `actionPerformed` method and the exception caught in the `catch` block. One of them needs to be renamed. I rename the caught exception to `ex`:

```
                }catch (IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
```

Then I recompile and look at the list of errors.

### No errors left

Now there are no compile-time errors left. If this was my program, this is when I'd be making sure that it worked properly.

Comment: Dear Chai T. Rex, your answer was very helpful! :D But was even more helpful were your tips on fixing errors. As all I know in java was self taught I didn't really know how to handle a big list of errors. But your tips are going to help me very much moving forward in Java! Thank You! :D